# Is there a way to disable script echoing in the PowerShell ISE?

Tags: powershell-3.0, powershell-ise

Whenever I want to test execution of my script in the PowerShell ISE, the entire script gets echoed to the console before it executes. Then, any actual output from the script gets written starting on a line immediately afterward. This puts a lot of noise in the console, and can make it tricky to find where the script echo ends and the output begins.

Is there a way to disable this echoing of the script into the console?

Comment: Would Clear-Host be a suitable work-around?

Comment: @GuyThomas I'd rather not. That would make it more difficult to compare output between subsequent runs of the script.

Comment: Running PowerShell ISE (x86) was my issue. Running the 64 bit version fix it.

Answer (score 55):

Save the script at least once. This will prevent the "script echo" of contents of the script. Instead, it will only echo the path to the saved script when you run the script for testing.

Answer (score 7):

If you just want to make the onscreen output 'cleaner', just add:

```
cls
```

at the top of your powershell script. This will clear the output in the console. The script will still be written onscreen momentarily but it will be cleared as soon as your code actually starts executing.

Comment: This is what I actually looked for. Thanks

Comment: Simple, but works! Thanks!

Answer (score -3):

if you have a line, for example

```
cmd.exe /c "echo foo"
```

you can path it into null and therefore produce no output

```
cmd.exe /c "echo foo" > $null
```

so if you launch your .ps1 from the command line you can do something like this:

```
PS C:\Users\bodyi> foo.ps1 > $null
```

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem. This just removes the script's output, the script itself still gets printed.